# How To randomize timer duration between two floats

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, clone, instantiation

Currently, This code spawns my prefab with only 1 float aka 1 second or w.e. I'm wanting to spawn my prefab between a minimum float and maximum float but not sure what to do because I'm novice and still learning c# and unity.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Spawn : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    public GameObject coin;

    [SerializeField]
    float fTimeIntervals;

    [SerializeField]
    Vector2 v2SpawnPosJitter;

    float fTimer = 0;

    public CurrencyManager cm;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        fTimer = fTimeIntervals;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        fTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (fTimer <= 0)
        {
            fTimer = fTimeIntervals;
            Vector2 v2SpawnPos = transform.position;
            v2SpawnPos += Vector2.right * v2SpawnPosJitter.x * (Random.value - 0.5f);
            v2SpawnPos += Vector2.up * v2SpawnPosJitter.y * (Random.value - 0.5f);
            GameObject cmscript = Instantiate(coin, v2SpawnPos, Quaternion.identity, GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Canvas").transform);
            cmscript.GetComponent<AutoDestroy>().CM = cm;
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split your `fTimeIntervals` field into a `fMaxTimeInterval` field and a `fMinTimeInterval` field then use [`Random.Range`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html) when you reset the timer to set it to a value between those intervals.  You can even make a `ResetTimer` method to do this in `Start` and `Update` so if you change how you do it, you only have to change it in one place:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Spawn : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    public GameObject coin;

    [SerializeField]
    float fMinTimeInterval;

    [SerializeField]
    float fMaxTimeInterval;

    [SerializeField]
    Vector2 v2SpawnPosJitter;

    float fTimer = 0;

    public CurrencyManager cm;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        ResetTimer();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        fTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (fTimer <= 0)
        {
            ResetTimer();
            Vector2 v2SpawnPos = transform.position;
            v2SpawnPos += Vector2.right * v2SpawnPosJitter.x * (Random.value - 0.5f);
            v2SpawnPos += Vector2.up * v2SpawnPosJitter.y * (Random.value - 0.5f);
            GameObject cmscript = Instantiate(coin, v2SpawnPos, Quaternion.identity, GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Canvas").transform);
            cmscript.GetComponent<AutoDestroy>().CM = cm;
        }
    }

    void ResetTimer()
    {
        fTimer = Random.Range(fMinTimeInterval,fMaxTimeInterval);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what does the reset timer do? hopefully it doesn't conflict with my auto desroy script which destorys the prefab after a set time?

Comment: It won't prevent the gameobject from being destroyed. Also, you almost certainly aren't destroying the prefab, but a gameobject you instantiate from the prefab :)

Comment: Okay, so tried the script you gave me seems to work? did i need to add anything to it? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Didn't really understand what you meant, did you mean the timer?
Use random.range if you want a random number between min/max value
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html